# Map Annotation DidSelectAnnotationView w/ Popover issue

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, mapkit, uipopovercontroller

Here is my problem

I have a splitview controller with a TableView and a MapView. Fairly standard setup.

On tableview selection I send a notification to the mapview to find the the exact ID of the object I am looking for, within the annotations I have, and select it.

Here is a sample snip of code.

```
-(void)zoomToLocation:(NSNotification*)notification{
     NSLog(@"zoomToLocation:");
     NSNumber *storeID = [notification object];
     if (storeID ==nil || storeID.intValue == 0) {
         return;
     }
    //Find the store out of Core Data Here
    CLLocation *storeLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:zoomStore.latitude.doubleValue longitude:zoomStore.longitude.doubleValue];
    MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(storeLocation.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01));
    [self.cMapView setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
    for (CustomAnnotationPin *annot in self.cMapView.annotations) {
        if ([annot isKindOfClass:[RBMapAnnotationPin class]]) {
             if(zoomStore.storeID.intValue == annot.storeID.intValue){
                 [self.cMapView selectAnnotation:annot animated:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works 100% Correctly. I am able to "zoom" to a an annotative pin at will. The real problem is that I want to show a popover programmatically on selection of an annotation.

I am using the delegate function didSelectAnnotationView

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{
    if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"DidSelect");
    [self.cMapView deselectAnnotation:view.annotation animated:NO];
    selectedPin = view.annotation;
    if(!mapPop){
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        MapCalloutViewController *mapCallout = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mapCalloutVC"];
        //Find the store in Core Data with the proper ID from the selected pin ID and give it to the VC for data
        mapPop = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:mapCallout];
        [mapPop setDelegate:self];
        [mapPop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(370, 230)];
        [mapPop presentPopoverFromRect:view.bounds inView:view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(mapStoreSelectionChanged:)]) {
            [self.delegate mapStoreSelectionChanged:mapCallout.store];
        }
    }
}
```

So here is a the issue. The code works perfectly great in Simulator. I zoom to the location and the mapDelegate is called and pops the annotation.

On the device the code doesn't function the same way. On the device I have to double tap on the Store for the map popover to show (I have no idea why, so this is fairly frustrating).